# How to create an interactive tiled grouped list in PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I need to create something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/md5yW.png]

A grouped, tiled list. Elements in groups are automatically lined up by the desired amount of elements in each line. You can select or enter for each element, and you can also hide some of the groups. But all that I have found as yet are `QListView` and `QTableView`.

Comment: You should consider switching to pyside instead of pyQt. It has vavorable license terms and a much wider support base.

Comment: @arkascha, thanks for an advice, but how is this helps with my quesion? :)

Comment: Not at all, sorry. Which is why I wrote it as a "comment", not as an answer.

Comment: @arkascha, dont worry, that's ok. :) Thank you again, I'll definitely think about it.

Comment: PySide has definitely never had a wider support base than PyQt.